# Selenium 1 - switch to iframe without ID

Tags: selenium, iframe

The page i crape have removed the ID from their iframe, so I have a problem switching to the iframe, and I can't find any documentation to help me, so maybe there is someone here on Stack?

The url of the page is: http://www.klappen.se/boka/onlinebokning/

I'm using Selenium 1 and my code looks like this:

```
$this->_driver->switchTo()->getFrameByName("mainframe");
```

In my TargetLocator.php i have these functions:

```
<?php
// Copyright 2012-present Nearsoft, Inc

// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at

// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

namespace SeleniumClient;

require_once 'WebDriver.php';

class TargetLocator
{
    private $_driver;

    public function __construct(WebDriver $driver)
    {
        $this->_driver = $driver;
    }

    #region TargetLocator members
    /**
     * Move to a different frame using its index
     * @param Integer $frameIndex
     * @return current WebDriver
     */
    public function getFrameByIndex($frameIndex)
    {

        $this->_driver->getFrame($frameIndex);

        return $this->_driver;
    }

    /**
     * Move to different frame using its name
     * @param String $frameName
     * @return current WebDriver
     */
    public function getFrameByName($frameName)
    {
        //We should validate that frameName is string
        /*
        if ($frameName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("frameName", "Frame name cannot be null");
        }
        */

        $this->_driver->getFrame($frameName);

        return $this->_driver;
    }

    /**
     * Move to a frame element.
     * @param WebElement $frameElement
     * @return current WebDriver
     */
    public function getFrameByWebElement(WebElement $frameElement)
    {
        //We should validate that frameElement is string
        /*
        if (frameElement == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("frameElement", "Frame element cannot be null");
        }

        RemoteWebElement convertedElement = frameElement as RemoteWebElement;
        if (convertedElement == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("frameElement cannot be converted to RemoteWebElement", "frameElement");
        }
        */

        $frameId = $frameElement->getElementId();
        $target = array('ELEMENT' => $frameId);
        $this->_driver->getFrame($target);

        return $this->_driver;
    }

    /**
     * Change to the Window by passing in the name
     * @param String $windowName
     * @return current WebDriver
     */
    public function getWindow($windowName)
    {
        $this->_driver->getWindow($windowName);

        return $this->_driver;
    }

    /**
     * Change the active frame to the default
     * @return current WebDriver
     */
    public function getDefaultFrame()
    {
        $this->_driver->getFrame(null);

        return $this->_driver;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the active element on the page and returns it
     * @return WebElement
     */
    public function getActiveElement()
    {
        $webElement = null;

        $webElement = $this->_driver->getActiveElement();

        return $webElement;
    }


    /**
     *  Switches to the currently active modal dialog for this particular driver instance.
     * @return \SeleniumClient\Alert
     */
    public function getAlert()
    {
        // N.B. We only execute the GetAlertText command to be able to throw
        // a NoAlertPresentException if there is no alert found.
        //$this->_driver->getAlertText();
        return new Alert($this->_driver); //validate that the Alert object can be created, if not throw an exception, try to use a factory singleton o depency of injection to only use 1 instance
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I have tried them all, but can't get it to work. Is there anybody out there who can help:-)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how does the HTML of the page look like? Without this it is difficult to tell how you should be able to find the iframe...

Comment: @spcial, offcourse sorry - I have updated my question.

Comment: Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see you are looking for this iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://dlbookit3.dlsystems.se/dlbookitKSR/bmlogifilt/logifilt.aspx" style="height:700px; width:100%; border:0;"></iframe>
```

right? So you have a method like `getFrameByWebElement(WebElement)` which accepts a `WebElement`. I think you can use an `xpath` to find the `webElement` e.g.:

```
WebElement element = find(By.xpath("//iframe"));
getFrameByWebElement(element);
```

so far in theory this could work (this is Java, you have to adapt it for your php code). But if I analyze the HTML code of the page with chrome I cannot locate the `webElement` by using the xpath `//iframe`.

Still you can try... but it looks like that the page owner doesn't want its `iFrame` to be locateable anymore :-)

Comment: I cant get it to work, so maybe you are right that they dont want me to locate the iframe anymore:-) Thanks for your time:-)

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 `IFRAME` on the page so you can just find it by tag name. The page loaded very slowly for me but I'm in the US so that may have something to do with it. You may have to wait for the `IFRAME` to become available and then get a handle to it.